# Weird edges on texture maps?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking

I've been downloading or extracting models (Specifically from games) to study them  and  one thing I notice in all the textures are these weird striped or sometimes blurred lines around the edges.

I used this image texture as an example because it shows what Im talking about, but all of them seem to follow this pattern.

Whats the reason behind doing this and how can I achieve the same result?
[image]

Comment: Look sliek what happens when you use 'inpaint' node in the compositor on an image, spreading the pixels outward from the edge of each island. Not exactly, but similar.

Comment: If you are getting models from games, they are probably made out a software like substance painter... That's called Padding or dilation and is a process that happens after the generation of a texture. Its purpose is to dilate the borders of the UV islands to fill empty areas with similar pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same result, go to Render Properties > Render Engine : Cycles, then go to Bake, set the Target to Image Texture and set the Margin to the amount of pixels you want your texture to be expanded.